# Why is the law not enforced, that a couple must divorce if they have no children after ten years?

Tags: marriage, divorce, pru-urvu

Jewish law says that if a couple has no children after ten years of marriage, and the man is not allowed to take a second wife, they must get a divorce so the man can remarry and try again to fulfill the mitzvah of procreating. [Yevamot 64a; Rambam, Ishut 15:8]

But the law is not enforced, even when the couple is very observant.  The last Lubavitcher Rebbe is a case in point.  The Rema says in EH 1:3: "Nowadays, the custom is that one does not force in regards to this."  But how can he make optional, with no explanation, a clear Talmudic injunction codified in stone by the Rambam?

Is there a discussion of circumstances under which does the injunction not apply?

Comment: How about "how come we don't enforce a couple to get divorced if they haven't had children, considering it's an explicit law in the gemarra and Shulchan Aruch"?

Comment: ----------rephrased

Comment: @doubleAA -- So, why don't you reopen?

Comment: There was a rebbe in London who had no children, so he used to divorce his wife every 10 years and remarry her.

Comment: Perhaps more pointedly, why do Sephardim, not usually known to rely on the Rema, also hold leniently in this case?

Comment: @doubleAA -- Why is this question not reopened? It stood at 4 votes to reopen only yesterday, now it's down to 1.  How come?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi reopen votes age away after a few days if the post isn't successfully reopened. i dont recall offhand the exact details of the timeline. but the number of active votes you see can change over time.

Comment: @ Double AA -- Your very popular answer in that other post does not answer the question I pose here.  That should be clear.  As for votes to reopen expiring, I can't think of a reason why they should.  Can you provide a link to that "rule"?